# Resetting with angular in an Ionic application

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, reset

I am trying to make a reset button for my cost estimator I am building using Ionic Framework. Now I have a simple reset from when It was a web app but obviously that does not work with Ionic.

I know i have to use Angular and add a controller etc but I am a rookie when it comes to Angular/Ionic and need some help.

Here is my code for current reset

HTML:

```
<div><button class="button button-block button-stable" id="resBtn"  value="Reset">Reset</button></div>
```

JS:

```
//Reset Button//  
document.forms[0].addEventListener('reset', function() {
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('resultPrem').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('containerPrem').innerHTML = '';
});
```

It is resetting this:

```
 <div id="priceBlock">
 <h2 class="preText" > Standard = <span id="price"></span></h2>
 <h3 id="container">&nbsp</h3>
 <h2 class="preText">Express = <span id="pricePrem" ></span></h2>
 <h3 id="containerPrem">&nbsp</h3>
```

I know i will have to add something like: ng(refresh) to the button then write a .controller in the app.js but could really do with some advice how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Fred

Comment: you have to clear whole form?

Comment: Yes the input and the price.

Comment: <input type="reset"> try this inside form

Answer (score 0):

You can refer angular docs
  [angular form guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

```
 <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
    Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
  </form>
  <pre>user = {{user | json}}</pre>
  <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      };

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };

      $scope.reset();
    }]);
</script>
```

note:snippent from guide